# Indian Passport, US Green Card, with valid Singapore visa. Does he need a separate Malaysian visa for short visit to Johor Bahru?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, singapore, malaysia

He is getting a Singapore Visa organized by a friend in Singapore for a visit. If he had to make a commute/short visit to Johor Bahru, Malaysia overland to pick up something, would he need a Malaysian visa or visa on arrival?

What would it cost?

Answer (score 2):

He will need a visa, most probably an eVisa (which has to be applied outside of Singapore: apparently they detect the IP address and block people in Singapore). VoA is only available at the airport, so that's out if he wants to cross overland.

A Green Card only gives you the right for a transit visa in KLIA, so that's out too.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia